# Ingresar arreglo a un Custom GridView

Tags: android, gridview

Me gustaría saber como meter datos de un arreglo a un Custom GridView, cuando solo se trata de llenar a un simple Gridview se hace así:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, miArreglo);

   gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Pero en este caso, agrego las celdas programáticamente mediante una clase `Adapter`. Entonces para generarlos los asigno al gridView que ya está creado en el `Layout`:

```
customgridviewadapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity());
        gridview.setAdapter(customgridviewadapter);
```

¿Ahora mi duda es como agregar datos de un arreglo a un `gridview` al cual le agrego celdas desde código?

Ya que solo se le puede asignar un `adapter`:

```
gridview.setAdapter();
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Tengo la `activity` `GridFragment`:

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {
    CustomGridViewAdapter gridViewElement;


   private GridView grid;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gridfragment, container, false);

      //Aquí está el arreglo que quiero que se coloque en el gridView
        String palabra = "abcdefghijklmno";
        String [] preguntaRespuesta = palabra.split("");    

        grid = (GridView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.gridViewLayout);

         grid.setNumColumns(13);


        gridViewElement = new CustomGridViewAdapter();

             grid.setAdapter(gridViewElement);



        return rootview;
    }


}
```

Este es `CustomGridViewAdapter`:

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;



    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context)
    {
        //super(context, 0);
        this.context=context;


    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return 169;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
     //Cargo un Custom Edittext en cada celda
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);








            EditText editTextCelda = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.gridEdittext);
            editTextCelda.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);

            final int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


        if (editTextCelda.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            if(sdk < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                editTextCelda.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_edittext));
            } else {
                editTextCelda.setBackground( context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_edittext));
            }

        } else{
            editTextCelda.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }







        return row;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respuesta al último comentario**:

> Pues gracias antes que todo, de hecho eso lo había probado igual, pero
>   me gustaría que se generen una cierta cantidad de celdas por ejemplo
>   100 y que los datos del arreglo se metan y ocupen solo las celdas
>   correspondienetes, ya que de esa forma solo se generan las celdas
>   dependiendo el tamaño del arreglo :/ no se si habrá una forma de hacer
>   eso, generar x cantidad de celdas y meter el arreglo y dejando vacías
>   el resto , es decir, si se generan 100 celdas y el arreglo solo tiene
>   10, que me aparezcan las 90 celdas restantes.

Vamos a añadir un parámetro más al constructor de tu adaptador que será una `ArrayList` de `Celdas` que tendrá un atributo llamado `arreglo` y rellenamos el gridview con los datos del mismo.

**Celda:**

```
   public class Celda{

        private String arreglo;

        public Celda(String arreglo) {
            this.arreglo = arreglo;
        }

        public void setArreglo(String arreglo) {
            this.arreglo = arreglo;
        }

        public String getArreglo() {
            return arreglo;
        }
    }
```

**ArrayList de Celdas**

```
ArrayList<Celda> alCeldas = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String arreglo = "";
        alCeldas.add(new Celda(arreglo));
    }
customgridviewadapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), alCeldas);
        gridview.setAdapter(customgridviewadapter);
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Celda> alCeldas;
    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Celda> alCeldas)
    {
        //super(context, 0);
        this.context=context;
        this.alCeldas= alCeldas;

    }

public int getCount()
{
    return alCeldas.size();
}

@Override
public Celda getItem(int position) {
    return alCeldas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public void insetarArreglo(String arreglo, int posicionArreglo){
   alCeldas.get(posicionArreglo).setArreglo("arreglo");
   this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
 //Cargo un Custom Edittext en cada celda
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);

        EditText editTextCelda = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.gridEdittext);
        editTextCelda.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        editTextCelda.setText(alCeldas.get(position).getArreglo());// con esta linea rellenamos los EditText del gridview con los datos del ArrayList

        final int sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


    if (editTextCelda.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        if(sdk < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            editTextCelda.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_edittext));
        } else {
            editTextCelda.setBackground( context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_edittext));
        }

    } else{
        editTextCelda.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    return row;
    }

}
```

**Insertar un arreglo:**

Si te fijas el adaptador tiene un método llamado `insertarArreglo`donde tienes que poner la posición de la celda donde quieres insertar el arreglo:

```
customgridviewadapter.insertarArreglo("miArreglo", posicionDelaCelda);
```

Eso es todo, Un saludo.

Comment: Mira, es un arreglo llamado `String [] miArreglo`, y quiero meter los datos que tiene a el `Gridview`, pero como ya he usado el   `setAdapter()`  para crear celdas y  no se como llenar ese  `Gridview`.Disculpa mi ignorancia...

Comment: Ok muestrame el código del CustomGridViewAdapter y te ayudo

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta con el código que pides, gracias.

Comment: Comprueba el último edit y comentame que tal :)

Comment: Pues gracias antes que todo, de hecho eso lo había probado igual, pero me gustaría que se generen una cierta cantidad de celdas por ejemplo 100 y que los datos del arreglo se metan y ocupen solo las celdas correspondienetes, ya que de esa forma solo se generan las celdas dependiendo el tamaño del arreglo :/ no se si habrá una forma de hacer eso, generar x cantidad de celdas y meter el arreglo y dejando vacías el resto , es decir, si se generan 100 celdas y el arreglo solo tiene 10, que me aparezcan las 90 celdas restantes.

Comment: Vale entonces lo vamos a plantear de diferente forma.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40957/discussion-between-fabio-venturi-pastor-and-x4mp73r).

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que debes realizar esto es:

modificar el arreglo, enviarlo al `Adapter`, en este caso `CustomGridViewAdapter()` y volver a ejecutar:

```
   .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

me parece que es la única forma, tener un array de datos dinámico.